# Windows 10 Activated Automatically

Tags: windows, windows-10, license

I format my Laptop yesterday and install Windows 10.

I didn't add a license key, but it seems like windows 10 activated automatically.

How was that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 was already installed before you formatted (that seems certain). So then when Windows installs, it looks to the Microsoft Licensing server and activates itself.  This is normal. It is the same machine and the Licensing server knows about that.

This may also allow you to replace a hard drive (SSD) on the same computer without any issues. Some changes (or more changes) may also require re-activation, and that is easy to do

Comment: I disagree with the last part. Replacing just the harddrive SSD will likely work, but replacing the harddrive and RAM upgrade at the same time may cause Microsoft to think it is a different computer and then it won't work.

Comment: That was merely an example of how activation can help. I have replaced hard drive with SSD (for speed) and Windows did not see it as enough of a change to require re-activation. Different changes may bring different results.

Comment: Yes I know, but others may see that statement and change more than just the harddrive, then get locked out and vote you down. Better safe than sorry stating that changing just one piece of hardware will work, rather than not mentioning it, assuming the user will understand.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you overall.  I edited my answer.